# How to trigger an SVG animation with JavaScript? (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have an SVG line path animated with this sample I found:

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
}

.path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 290;
  stroke-dashoffset: 130;
  animation: dash 6s 0s forwards infinite;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 290;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 25 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path class="path" d="M0 50 L 12 50, 12 0, 25 0" fill="transparent"></path>
</svg>
```

It works fine but it's triggered when the page loads. Is there a way (let's say with a button) to trigger this animation using JavaScript?

I can handle JS but I'm a noob with CSS and SVG animations.

Can anybody give me an example of how I can do it with my actual CSS?

Comment: [This](https://mb.sb/tech/animations/animations.html) is a small example I've written that shows how to animate an SVG with the browser's [web animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API). It includes a button and slider to animate the SVG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use SMIL animation syntax instead of CSS animation. This admittedly has the downside of not running in Microsoft browsers (both IE and Edge).

```js
var animation = document.getElementById("dash");

function showSVG() {
  animation.beginElement();
}
```

```css
svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
}

.path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 290;
  stroke-dashoffset: 290;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="showSVG()">Click</button>
<svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 25 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="path" d="M0 50 L 12 50, 12 0, 25 0" fill="transparent">
  <animate id="dash" 
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    from="290" to="0"
    begin="indefinite" 
    dur="6s" 
    fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

This animation runs once every time you click. If you want it to repeat in fixed intervals, like CSS `animation-repeat: infinite` prescribes, use

```
<animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    from="290" to="0"
    begin="indefinite" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
}

.path {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
    stroke-dashoffset: 130;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-dashoffset: 290;
}

.animated {
    animation: dash 6s 0s forwards infinite;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 290;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can add the class .animated to your path with js whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your animation in a css class:

```
    .dash-animate {
        animation: dash 6s 0s forwards infinite;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
      from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 290;
      }
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

And then simply apply that class when/where you want using js:

```
var button = getElementById('some-button');

button.addEventListner('click', function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.path');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.classList.add('dash-animate');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var svgPattern = document.getElementById("svg")
svgPattern.style.display = "none";
function showSVG(){
svgPattern.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
                svg{
                    position:absolute;
                    width:100%;
                    height:100%;
                    left:0%;
                    top:0%;
                    display:block;
                    background:transparent;
                }
                
                .path {
                    stroke:black;
                    stroke-dasharray: 290;
                    stroke-dashoffset: 130;
                    animation: dash 6s 0s forwards infinite;
                    stroke-width:2px;
                    stroke-linecap:round;
                    stroke-linejoin:round;
                }
                
                @keyframes dash {
                  from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 290;
                  }
                  to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                  }
                }
```

```html
<button id ="button" onclick="showSVG()">Click</button>
               <svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 25 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path class="path" d="M0 50 L 12 50, 12 0, 25 0" fill="transparent"></path>
                </svg>
```